# Substring in Left Join condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to do substring within the join condition, but it is not working.

```
SELECT    
  IF (ps.shop = 'NL',TopCat.Parent_Title, CategoryUID.Parent_Title) as Parent_Title,
  IF (ps.shop = 'NL',TopCat.Sub_Title_1, CategoryUID.Sub_Title_1) as Sub_Title_1,
  IF (ps.shop = 'NL',TopCat.Sub_Title_2, CategoryUID.Sub_Title_2) as Sub_Title_2,
  ps.ean, ps.product_resource_id        
FROM `xxlhoreca-bi.PriceSearch.XXL_PriceComparison` ps
LEFT JOIN
  `xxlhoreca-bi.DataImport.TopCategories` topCat
ON
  ps.product_resource_id = topCat.product_resource_id
LEFT JOIN
  `DataImport.CategoryUID` CategoryUID
ON
  SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR('DataImport.CategoryMappingWithLocalID.Reporting_ID', 4) AS INT64) = CategoryUID.Category_ID
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is there any way around how I can write `substring` within `LEFT JOIN` condition?

I need to change the `substring` part, but I have not been able to achieve it. Any helps would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and what YOU mean by "not working".  Also, joining on a constant value doesn't seem particularly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on roughly the right track.

I am going to make a few assumptions here so bear with me, but I think there are educated guesses.

1. I think this `DataImport.CategoryMappingWithLocalID.Reporting_ID` is a field (Reporting_ID) from a table (CategoryMappingWithLocalID) you have in your dataset (DataImport).
2. What you are trying to achieve is to get the categories that are included in your CategoryMappingWithLocalID.
3. You are trying to get a substring from the `Reporting_ID` field because it has the ID you want within the first 4 characters.
4. Because `SUBSTR` requires a string, you are trying to turn that dataset.table.field reference in a string by putting it in single quotes, which leads me to think it might actually be a numeric field in the original table.

Now, the solution.

1. You need to use the table in your query if you want to use it in your JOIN ON clause. Therefore, you need to add an extra JOIN there.
2. You are on the right track with the SUBSTR part, but what you need to use is `CAST(field AS STRING)` to convert your numeric value into a string.

Put those two things together in your query and you are ready to go my friend.

```
JOIN `DataImport.CategoryMappingWithLocalID` AS category_mapping
    ON 
SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(CAST(DataImport.CategoryMappingWithLocalID.Reporting_ID AS STRING), 4) AS INT64) = CategoryUID.Category_ID
```